# App restarts, Doesn't run due to AndroidRuntime Exception

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

**Gradle build is successful logcat shows E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main**

**--------Logcat Error-----------**

```
07-27 23:04:54.813 21702-21702/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.inoalexander.justjava, PID: 21702
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.inoalexander.justjava/com.example.inoalexander.justjava.mainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.inoalexander.justjava.mainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1534)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1424)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.inoalexander.justjava.mainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.inoalexander.justjava-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2809)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1534) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1424)
```

**---------Java Code starts here----------**

```
package com.example.inoalexander.justjava;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
* This app displays an order form to order coffee.
*/
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    display(1);
}

/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
private void display(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView)            findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

**---------XML code starts here-------------**

```
<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Quantity" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="0" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_id"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Order"
    android:onClick="submitOrder"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not to sure as this is one of the first apps I've built that isn't a card. I'm not sure why it isn't running on my phone. I'm using a Galaxy Note 5 to run my build.

The `Gradle` build is successful and gives me no errors but when I try to run it on my device it keeps trying to restart the app until it eventually crashes the app. I have looked at a few answers here and was instructed to look at my `Logcat` in android studio.

I honestly don't know were to even begin within `Logcat` or what it even tells me, there are a lot of variations of this error I have seen but not one specific to each of the errors in my `Logcat`.

Comment: Show us what you've done to debug this.

Comment: Does the AndroidManifest.xml contains the activity name?

Comment: can you post your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

set `multidex` true to app level `build.gradle` file like below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.core.######"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true // here change
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
}
```

also add dependency

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

finally don't forget to clean and rebuild project.

Comment: thank you for the info, what does enabling multidex do?

Answer (score 0):

The exception says it's trying to find class `mainActivity` but in your code you have `MainActivity`.

Make sure the activity class name in `AndroidManifest.xml` matches your code.

Comment: Thank you so much I went through everyone's comments before reading this one and as luck has it the simplest one was the solution!